# Where does Chrome store login credentials in macOS?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, high-sierra, mojave

I swear I've seen this question thoroughly answered somewhere before but I [couldn't find the answer](https://www.google.com/search?q=where%20does%20Chrome%20store%20passwords%20in%20macOS%3F%20OSX&sa=G&gbv=1&sei=rmm_W5aWG4eX0gLa-LGICw) I'm looking for...

Chrome secures our [saved passwords](http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Chrome-for-Mac-saved-passwords.png) in the System.keychain, right? But when I view my Keychain, the passwords aren't there. Could someone clarify where Chrome stores saved passwords and which files in macOS (Mojave) are actually storing the (probably encrypted) credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume you are not confusing Google and Chrome.

Google application passwords are stored in your KeyChain, for things like Gmail, Calendar, Google drive ect..

Chrome passwords are stored on your HD at

`~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/databases` in special format. (SQL)

However Chrome is a browser and its passwords for diverse websites is not stored in the KeyChain.

Comment: which version of Chrome/macOS are you using? The `/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/databases` file/directory doesn't exist for me in Mojave with Chrome 69. In fact, there's no "Google" directory in Application Support at all. The only "databases" directory I could find was `/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/databases/Databases.db`. Is this the file you're referring to?

Comment: yes that one, they moved it, and I apologize, I skipped a special character (~) `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome`

Answer (score 1):

All of your Chrome passwords are encrypted by Chrome and stored in an SQLite database file under Chrome's Local App Data. It is not stored via Keychain.

If you would like to know more about the technical details, refer [this](https://superuser.com/questions/146742/how-does-google-chrome-store-passwords) answer.

Comment: Thanks. But the article you linked to mostly talks about `CryptProtectData`, a function specific to Windows 10. Could you elaborate what you mean by "SQLite database file under Chrome's Local App Data"? Are you referring to the `/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome` directory? Which file is the SQLite db?

Comment: On my MBA the Google/Chrome passwords are in the KeyChain

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the case any longer.  I'm using Chrome Version 76.0.3809.132.  When I start Chrome and get the question to 'Allow Always', 'Deny', or 'Allow' access to the keychain, I Deny its use of the keychain.  In Chrome, I have 'Offer to save passwords' and 'Auto Sign-in' on and it never asks me to save passwords and I cannot do it manually (using the key icon to the right of the address bar) as the key icon never shows.  I exited Chrome and re-started, this time Allowing Chrome to use the keychain and now it asks me to save passwords and the key icon displays.  Also, I do not have a /Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/databases file nor a /Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default directory.