# Is it possible to open Chrome's databases.db in another MacBook?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, google-chrome, mojave

This is in response to [another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339281/where-does-chrome-store-login-credentials-in-macos) I found interesting. Is it possible for an attacker to copy Chrome passwords found in `/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/databases/Databases.db` and view them on another MacBook?

@Buscar웃

Answer (score 1):

They certainly can but they need your keychain password from the originating MacBook.

On Windows the password store is encrypted using your system password.
 Regardless, any system ought to be encrypted and should never share your keychain password with anyone.